# How can I reduce a list of arguments, instead of a collection?

Tags: clojure

Is there a function in clojure that takes two or more arguments and supplies them to a function, so f(f(f(a, b), c), d) etc.

I know I can do something like this:

```
(fn g [& items] (reduce f (seq items)))
```

But is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly how you should do it. In fact removing `seq` would make it even simpler without changing the behaviour.

Comment: Doh! I didn't think it would work without seq, but that's ace.  Still trying to get my head around bindings... thanks!

Comment: items is already a clojure.lang.ArraySeq, so you don't need to apply seq to it.